# c# Возвратить список readonly экземпляров пользовательского класса.

Tags: c#

Есть пользовательский класс **Student**

```
public Student
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Student(string name, Teacher teacher)
    {
        Name = name; 
        teacher.AddStudent(this);
    }
}
```

Есть второй пользовательский класс в котором хранится обобщенная коллекция экземпляров класса Student

```
public Teacher
{
    private List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    public List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return students;
    }
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        students.Add(student);
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы метод **GetStudents()** класса **Teacher** отдавал коллекцию экземпляров класса **Student**, которые будут доступны только для чтения?

Comment: если вы не хотите, чтобы у студента можно было изменить значения полей - сделайте у них приватный set

Comment: В том то и дело, что необходимо, чтобы свойства у класса Student остались изменяемыми, кроме случая, когда объект класса Teacher отдает список своих студентов - только для чтения. По аналогии в обычной жизни: в деканате есть список студентов, каждую запись этого списка можно править. Каждый студент прикреплен к одному учителю. У учителя просят список его студентов. Он его просто "показывает", но не дает права на изменение. Можно было бы просто отправить информацию о студентах в виде string, но очень хотелось бы отдавать readonly объекты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автоматом такое не делается. Значит сделаем вручную.

---

### Простой способ

Предлагаю в методе `Teacher.GetStudents` отдавать копии экземпляров класса `Student`. В этом случае они, конечно, будут изменяемыми, но при внесении в них изменений оригиналы не пострадают.

```
public class Teacher
{
    private readonly List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    public List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return students.ConvertAll(s => new Student(s.Name, this));
    }

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        if (!students.Contains(student))
            students.Add(student);
    }
}
```

Еще в этом случае необходимо проверять коллекцию на дубликаты в методе `AddStudent`.

---

### Способ посложнее

Можно сделать класс `ImmutableStudent`, который был бы неизменяемым. Чтобы минимизировать различия классов для остальной программы, предлагаю ввести общий интерфейс `IStudent`:

```
public interface IStudent
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public sealed class ImmutableStudent : IStudent
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ImmutableStudent(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Student : IStudent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Student(string name, Teacher teacher)
    {
        Name = name;
        teacher.AddStudent(this);
    }
}
```

И отдавать в классе `Teacher` так:

```
public class Teacher
{
    private readonly List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    public List<IStudent> GetStudents()
    {
        return students.ConvertAll(s => (IStudent)new ImmutableStudent(s.Name));
    }

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        students.Add(student);
    }
}
```